# call & execute the shell script within expect script

Tags: expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh derrick@$abc123.net
expect "password"
send "helloworld\n"
send "cd /tmp\n"
send "sh rename.sh\n" # this shell script will get a list of files and rename each file
send "exit\n"
expect eof
```

The problem is when `'rename.sh'` started and within less than 3 seconds, the `'expect'` script exits while `'rename.sh'` is not yet done executed.

My question is how can I make my expect script to wait for the finish of  'rename.sh' execution?

Comment: Please, when you've found an answer that solves your problem, **accept** it by clicking at its green tick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that disabling the timeout in the beginning would work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use timeout in expect script

example : set timeout < in seconds>

set timeout 8

Comment: This is not a very satisfying solution. What happens if the command takes more than 8 seconds to run?